# how to do this in Python (perl snippet to sort a 2D array)

Tags: python, perl

I am trying to write this snippet in Python, to do a 2D array sort. Basically, I have an array of arrays, and I need to sort it by the second element first, then by the first

can anyone help out?

```
my @result = sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] || $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @all
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html try here, if you get stuck, let us know what you've tried and what worked and what didn't...

Comment: Actually, I found out the problem. In Perl, there is automatic type conversion from string to integer, whereas in python, that is not the case. I fixed this logic flaw in my Python code, and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
from operator import itemgetter

all = [ [2,2],[2,1],[1,2],[1,1] ]
result = sorted(all, key=itemgetter(0,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_sort(a, b):

    return cmp(a[0], b[0]) or cmp(a[1], b[1]);


AnArray = [ [3, 3], [2, 6], [2, 2], [0, 4], [0, 1] ];

print AnArray
print sorted(AnArray, cmp=my_sort)
```

Comment: Things I've read say the cmp parameter was removed in python 3